# Does typing increase speed of execution when wrapping C functions with Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

I am using Cython to wrap some C code. This is the declaration of a typical routine (the actual ones involve about 13 to 17 arguments).

```
void my_func(double *__restrict__ lhs, const int xlhs, const int oxlhs);
```

Right now, in the .pyx file this is how I define the wrapper

```
def preCond1D(np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] lhs not None, xlhs not None, oxlhs not None): 
   preCond1D_func( <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(lhs), xlhs, oxlhs)
```

Would there be any benefit (performance or otherwise) if instead I explicitly declare (i.e. typing) the int variables, as

```
def preCond1D(np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] lhs, xlhs: cython.int32, oxlhs: cython.int32): 
   preCond1D_func( <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(lhs), xlhs, oxlhs)
```

Comment: AFAIK, type hints have no effect in Python.

Comment: I understand, but this .pyx file is translated in C and then compiled, so it could add extra layers of type checking

Comment: It could, but I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Cython does use type hints, so generally they are useful. You can control this by the `annotation_typing` directive.

In this case though they'll make absolutely no difference. You will get exactly one set of data conversions from Python values to C types. With the type hints they'll happen right at the start of `preCond1D`. Without the type hints they'll happen at the call to `preCond1D_func`.

The only benefit would be the documentation that the type hints provide.

Comment: I want to point out that annoting can be set for pure mode but the conversion has to be set with the correct type (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html). The docs state that a python `int` will not be converted to a proper int in C and cython.int has to be used for this.